# make up an integer's binary representation

Tags: c, binary

Here is the thing, `1024 = 0x400`, and I assume its binary representation (little endian) is `\\x00\\x4\\x00\\x00`. And I try to do something like this,

```
int main()
{
    const char *str = "\\x00\\x4\\x00\\x00";
    const int *p = (const int *)str;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
}
```

But why the above code can't give me `1024`?

Comment: Also, `p` is most definitely not a pointer to an `int`, so this is pure undefined behaviour. At the very least you should check the size!

Comment: "definitely undefined behaviour"? :)

Comment: @KerrekSB, but by `printf "\\x00\\x4\\x00\\x00"` gives me `1024`.

Comment: @MichaelKrelin-hacker, linux bash.

Comment: In shell I'd expect this command to actually output binary 1024 (these bytes), not the 1024 representation you'd expect from `printf` normally.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Because you escaped `\`. Unescape them:

```
const char *str = "\x00\x4\x00\x00";
```

Comment: Yes, that's right. I was confused by `printf "\\x00\\x4\\x00\\x00"` in linux bash.

Comment: `bash` first unescapes string and then processes. Though I'm not sure if this printf would yield `1024`…

Comment: But it `printf '\x00\x4\x00\x00'` also gives me `1024` in shell, so I guess I shouldn't use "\\".

Comment: Shell escaping is a totally different matter ;)

Answer (score 4):

You have too many backslashes in the string.

Try this instead:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    const char *str = "\x00\x4\x00\x00";
    const int *p = (const int *)str;
    printf("%d\n", *p);
    return 0;
}
```

Output at [ideone](http://ideone.com/Rd9SL):

```
1024
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you know what happens when you enter a newline character at the end of any printf statement i.e., **\n**, the **"\"** part is known as the escaping slash. That's why **\n** doesn't gets printed. The same way if you give **"\\x00\\x4\\x00\\x00"**, it means **\x00\x4\x00\x00** will get stored which obviously doesn't means anything. So, you have to get rid of those **\ (these slashes)**. Thus,

```
const char *str = "\x00\x4\x00\x00";
```

will happily do your work. :-)